# How to free the UART pins of Raspberry pi B+ from acting as a kernel console?

Tags: raspbian, serial, uart, serial-console

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ for my project with Raspbian Jessie OS installed on it.. I have to receive "Real-time" electric current values coming from a wireless Nordic module. So to start this serial communication I am trying to free the UART pins from showing the kernel output. For this purpose I tried the steps mentioned on this link: 
[Using UART on Raspberry Pi – Python](https://electrosome.com/uart-raspberry-pi-python/).

This asks me to make two changes - one in `cmdline.txt` file and the other in `/etc/inittab` file. I was successful in making the first change. However, for the other step, I could not find the `/etc/inittab` file in my Raspberry Pi b+. What should I do now to make my RPi be able to receive the Serial Data from the Nordic module?

Can someone please help me out quickly, as it is urgent project!

Comment: Try sudo systemctl stop getty.target

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, but the simplest is to run `sudo raspi-config` - The `Advanced` option has a setting to disable console.

Comment: Will that take care of both the config.txt file AND the "serial-console" spawning of a `getty` instance or just the first of those - which the OP has already sorted? 8-)

Comment: @SlySven Yes, AFAIK it should do both. I have been using serial for many purposes with no problems (unless I get the baud rate wrong ;-)

Comment: Can you posting up the changes that `raspi-config` makes to the files (what ever they are?) that toggling the state does - or is it all buried in a binary "registry" that only `systemd` understands?

Comment: @SlySven if you want to see how it works try `cat /usr/bin/raspi-config`. I have tried looking through it before - there are 1300 lines of code, and it not that easy to follow.

Comment: Ah, spaghetti code!  I'll have to dive into a pasta meal.   8-@==<

Answer (score 1):

On `systemd` enabled systems, to disable the serial console from starting on boot run:

```
sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
```

In `systemd`, `start`/`stop` starts/stops the service now (but not on boot) and `enable`/`disable` starts/stops the service on boot (but not now).

Answer (score 0):

What @joan was hinting at in their comment was that those original instructions relate to the `/etc/inittab` file which is used by SysV `init` the default "first process" on Raspbian versions up to the previous one which was "Wheezy".  As of "Jessie" the default has changed to `systemd` and most people using Rasbian will be using that. {I am an exception and have taken the option that is still there in Jessie to stick with the older one and had to do exactly what you are doing so that my RPi can talk to a UPS add-on}.  The `sudo systemctl stop getty.target` is probably the command you have to tell that new-fangled `systemd` to stop running a `getty` on the serial port - which is what the original changes to the `/etc/inittab` would have done.

As I say - I have virtually no exposure to `systemd` - but I am uncertain whether that change would be permanent or would have to be done each time the RPi is booted.  It may be that you will have to edit a "service file" I think they call it, if you want to permanently produce the same effect.

Comment: Hey @SlySven! I tried that command sudo systemctl stop getty.target . After that I checked on minicom and did not see the text ( Uncompressing Li) on the screen. But then when I reboot the raspberry pi, and then check the output on the minicom, the kernel output (i.e. Uncomressing Li) is seen again. How to keep that change permanent??

Comment: That is why I warned that I am not knowledgeable about `systemd` - I do not know! - I was only reiterating/expanded on what @joan had said...

Comment: `getty.target` will stop all gettys, you only wnat to stop the serial getty.

Comment: Can you say how to do that?  I don't have a `systemd` setup to experiment on! 8-P